# How to define the response?

Tags: python, django, http

I want to fix a question.Like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime
def current_datetime(request):
          now = datetime.datetime.now()
          if now == 2013:
                          html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
                          return HttpResponse(html)
          else:
                         # giva a response first 
                         urllib.urlopen(message)
                         # do something 
                         print 'not 2013'
                         sys.exit(0)
```

How to use " urllib.urlopen(message)" instead of "HttpResponse()" ?
NOT use HttpResponse() But give a response. 
Thank you.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do  ?

Comment: @karthikr NOT use HttpResponse() But give a response.

Comment: You mean give a response in the console or something? Or do you mean an alternative to `HttpResponse` ?

Comment: `return Httpresponse('not 2013')` MIGHT WORK. BUT what you mean by urllib.urlopen. you want to `import urllib` first and `urllib` is used to fetch html from urls eg:-http://google.com. not to show message

Comment: @karthikr Thank you, yes. Because I want to do something after give a response.

Comment: @suhail I want to do something after give a response. So not Httpresponse

Comment: @suhail So, I need how to give a response, not use urlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience with Django, each function that you hand a request via views must eventually return an HttpRequest object. Why do you need to do the "something" specifically after sending the response rather than before?

Comment: Thank you.I need give a responson immediatly, and do something

Comment: What sort of response do you need to give? Also, it may not be a good idea to exit from Python in the else clause. Have you considered redirecting the user to a different page instead? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think I can't define a response, because a HTTP connection actually is a TCP, so I can't rebuild a TCP in the TCP of HTTP. Thank you.